# Receive credit card payment sending my customer details to a credit card processing company?

Tags: credit-card, payment

I would like to receive credit card payments for my business (tourist apartment).  I actually get my guests via the booking.com website. This company provides me the guests' credit card details. But I don't have any POS equipment because it's very expensive to buy or rent one here (Cyprus). Are there any web-based companies that can do the process for me (I am sending the details, they make the processing, then transfer to my account)?

Comment: Have you considered paypal et al?

Comment: I've seen a lot of small businesses using Square. Don't know much about it, but it might be something to check out.

Comment: Square is a good option but they charge more for manual entry. ~1.25 percent more. You may be better off finding a merchant that will lease you the equipment for free.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are a bunch. I have used Paypal and it worked quite nicely. I see endless ads these days for Square, a tiny card reader that you plug into a smartphone that lets you swipe the card. (With Paypal you have to type in the credit card number.)

Comment: The little box is Square, probably.

Comment: @joe Yes, thanks, I couldn't think of the name and I had to get back to work so I didn't want to take the time to look it up. :-)

Comment: No problem.  Added to the post.

Comment: There are several competitors to Square -- I know Staples gas one under their own brand, and there are  others out there. We can't recommend, since the deals being offered nay change at any time. Shop around, and recheck every year or two to see if soneone can offer you a better option.

Comment: Paypal actually has their own version of the card reader, no need to type anything in. My comic book guy uses this for his store.